# Getting javascript Error in CodeMirror version 0.4

Tags: 2013, cme, gui-extensions

I am getting javascript error when i am trying to use CodeMirror version 0.4 to use dremweaver autocomplete functionality.
When i am trying to create new tbb or opening existing tbb that time on source tab only "loading" is coming and nothing is happening.
I download code from "https://github.com/buildingblocks/tridion-mirror" and use manual step to deploy.

[image]

Please help me for the same.

Comment: CodeMirror supports Tridion 2011 and 2013. Which version are you on?

Comment: I am using sdl tridion 2013

Answer (score 1):

0.4 wasn't released - just available from github. You could try turning off minification, I think I got stuck trying to fix an issue with that.

Try installing 0.32 from here http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/codemirror.aspx

I haven't really updated it in a while so no guarantee it won't have a few issues.

I've been working on an Alchemy plugin to do the same job but not finished it yet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rob that code is working fine and giving syntax highlighting but i need dreamweaver auto complete functionality for that i tried installing new version https://github.com/buildingblocks/tridion-mirror/tree/master/chocolatey-package/content but it is giving me javascript error  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined" . It is coming in "tridion-code-mirror-extension.js" and not getting id of MasterTabControl i guess